# Query object field that may not always exist

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function in Typescript that returns a value which is either one of two custom Types.

For example:

```
export function funcName(): TypeA | TypeB {
   //function code
}
```

In this example, I'll make the Types look like this:

```
export interface TypeA {
    name: 'name';
    other_var: 'random';
}

export interface TypeB {
    name: 'name';
    different_var: 'new';
}
```

I then want to query the returned value from my function and apply an if statement based on `other_var` as follows:

```
let val = funcName();
if (val.other_var=='XYZ') {
   //do this
}
```

However, this is giving me an issue because `other_var` may not always be a part of val:

```
Property 'other_var' does not exist on type 'TypeB'
```

Basically, if the Type is TypeB I'm not interested in going in to the if block anyway but I'm struggling to get a solution that doesn't result in an error. I can't seem to do a check for whether it is TypeA or B

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://simplernerd.com/typescript-dynamic-json/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `hasOwnProperty`. Something like:

```
let val = funcName();
if (val.hasOwnProperty("other_var")) {
  if (val.other_var=='XYZ') {
   //do this
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but I don't think it works for interfaces

Comment: And what about `hasOwnProperty` ? Let me update answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing).  For example:

```
if ('other_var' in val && val.other_var=='XYZ') {
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=50#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWNWgOQEMBbYACgEoAuOAFQE8xgBBOAH3qeACE4BvAFBwRAelHJ0WHHDQQAJsGEiowGEii5+KUsFoByHWX0AaOBBgALYFAD6ANyJQDUIinkQS+gL6Dfg0EhYOEwUGBsEIjRgLmY2IRERIz04Q119AG5lEQtrO0dnVNd3T0y-QQDwaHhQ8KhI6NjeAWy4ZINkssS4eUwEBBtgMIcnDuAAdzL-ABs1OEdpuABePHRiMiosvrhyfVybEah9ENwFuAAyc-miaYA6ffynJaX9AA0ATQAtfUoWxPEPHArJgAM5+IA)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1: The Quick Fix

A way of doing this is to assign the object to type any. This type is generally used for dynamic content of which we may not know the specific type. Essentially, we are opting out of type checking that variable.

```
let val: any = {}

val = funcName();
if (val.other_var=='XYZ') {
   //do this
}
```

### Solution 2: The Proper Fix

Consistency is key. In order to stay consistent with the TypeScript standard, we can define an interface that allows keys of type string and values of type any.

```
interface ExampleObject {
    [key: string]: any
}

let val: ExampleObject = {};

val = funcName();
if (val.other_var=='XYZ') {
   //do this
}
```

What if this interface is only used once? We can make our code a little more concise with the following:

```
let val: {[k: string]: any} = {};

val = funcName();
if (val.other_var=='XYZ') {
   //do this
}
```

References: https://simplernerd.com/typescript-dynamic-json/